# Can someone explain the use of ...spread operator in the following example?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux

As per my understanding this is how spread operator works:

```
x=[1,2,3];

y=[...x,4,5];
```

> // this is same as y=[1,2,3,4,5]

```
const initialState={
  ingredients: [
    new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
    new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10),
  ]
};
export function shoppingListReducer( state=initialState, action:ShoppingListActions.ShoppingListActions ) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ingredients:[...state.ingredients,action.payload ]
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Here in the above example what does

```
return {
  ...state,
  ingredients:[...state.ingredients,action.payload ]
}
```

evaluate to?

Payload is of type Ingredient :

```
export class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) {}
}
```

Comment: You can spread objects too:`{  ...state}`  Here `state` is an object. And by using `{}` the result will be an object.

Comment: what is your payload type?

Comment: @RezaRahmati payload:Ingredients 
`export class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) {}
}
`

Comment: `Ingredients` is not the same as `Ingredient`. What is the type `Ingredients`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to create an object with all the properties of `state` object and overriding its property `ingredients` with value as all the values in `state.ingredients` array along with `action.payload`. This might be done to **separate the reference** of the result object from state object.

```js
var state = {
  "someprop" : "somevalue",
  "ingredients" : ["a", "b"]
};

var action = {
  "payload" : 4
};

var result = {
  ...state,
  ingredients:[...state.ingredients,action.payload ]
};
state.someprop = "somevalue1"; // does not alter result object
state.ingredients.push("c"); // does not alter result object
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, to understand it better, you can break that into following

```
var result = {...state};
result.ingredients = [...state.ingredients, action.payload];
```

**Note**: In case there is a nested object in `state` or an object in `array`, they will still continue to share the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

When used inside an object think of it as object.assign. the original state is added to object, then the next thing (ingredients), overwriting anything already there if necessary (ingredients), and so on down the line

Comment: Why the downvote? This helps him conceptualize and make sense of whats happening in an easy manner without loading it down with overly technical answers.